# Updating JSON data PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

What i'm trying to is `update` a column in my Database that uses Json data. I've started out with decoding the data and it shows the value of that particular data and i'm just stuck on what I should do next.

Login code

```
if(strtolower($_GET['action']) == "login")

{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password'] ) 
    {
        die("<div style='text-indent: 10px;color: #FF0000;margin-top: -27px;'>Error - Please fill out the required fields to login</div>");
    }

    if($username == null)    return;

    if($password == null)    return;


    if(!$conn)    die("MySQL Error.");

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username= :Player AND password= :Pass");
    $result->bindParam(':Player', $username); 
    $result->bindParam(':Pass', $password);
    $result->execute(); 

    if(!$result)    die("An Error has occured");

    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $c = unserialize($rows['addons']);
    $profileData = $rows['profile'];

    #gets json data from $profileData
    $json_a=json_decode($profileData,true);
    $json_o=json_decode($profileData);
    foreach($json_o->profile as $p)


    if(!$rows) die("<div style='text-indent: 10px;color: #FF0000;margin-top: -27px;'>Error - Username or Password was incorrect</div>");

    if($c['powers']['profile']['has'] == 0) die("<div style='text-indent: 10px;color: #FF0000;margin-top: -27px;'>Error - You don't have the available permission to edit your profile</div>");

    echo ("<div style='text-indent: 350px;position: absolute;  margin-top: 33px;'>Login as <b><a target='_blank' href='http://localhost/uprofile.php?u=$username'> $username </a></b></div>");
    ?>
```

This is where I decoded the data for the profile

```
 $json_a=json_decode($profileData,true);
        $json_o=json_decode($profileData);
        foreach($json_o->profile as $p)
```

The update code:

```
<?php
    }
    else
    if(strtolower($_GET['action']) == "publish")
    {
        $username = $_POST['myname'];
        $value = $_POST['value'];

        if(!$conn)        die("MySQL Error.");

        $q = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET profile = :Profile WHERE username= :Player ");
        $q->bindParam(':Player',$username);
        $q->bindParam(':Profile',$value);
        if($q->execute()){
                echo "<div style='text-indent: 10px;color: #008000;margin-top: -27px;'>Profile has been updated</div>";
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't update Profile";
            }

    }
    else
    {
        ?>
```

outputting the value `$p->detail`

as followed here

```
  <form action='?action=publish' method='post'>
    <textarea rows="30" cols="90" name="value" style="margin: 0px 0px 10px; width: 655px; height: 394px;">
    <?php echo $p->detail; ?>
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.
MD5 is *not* sufficient for password protection.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what i'm asking.

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but it *is* what you should be doing. That is why these are called comments. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ We don't know what you should do next, because it looks like you're doing an update. What do you want to do next?

Comment: I want the details in my json data to be updated i'm using this as the value to input in a textbx area : `$p->detail; ` and want it to be updated it through mysql as you can see in my code but I led myself to a stopping point that I don't know what to do next. Like do I have to encode it back into json for it to update?

Comment: If you push anything to the array/object then you have to encode it again.

Comment: Could you show me an example using my code? I'm new at using json so i'm not 100% sure how it would look in my updated code.

Comment: I cannot because I cannot unravel your code to find your array/object (is it `$json_a`? `$json_o`?). For instance, if it is `$json_o` you could say `$json_o->detail = $p->detail; $newJSON = json_encode($json_o);`

Comment: You didn't explain what you're trying to update, you didn't change anything in the decoded json so an update seems pointless. I recommend you save yourself a lot of grief down the line and store the data in separate columns instead of converting it to json

Comment: `$password == null` never triggered after md5...

Comment: What is the idea of decodiing a php array?!?!?!? $json_a=json_decode($profileData,true);

Comment: @andrew I did explain what I wanted to update. I wanted to update the value "detail" that is located in the JSON data and how it's updating is this http://i.imgur.com/77sEOf3.png